# php - authenticate against CAS client

Tags: php, authentication, cas

I'm developing a php application that connects to a customer website (Java+ExtJS) and fetches some data from there.

The problem is that customer's application doesn't have any external APIs available, so I need to use internal API designed specifically for ExtJS frontend.

The website is protected with CAS so I'm trying to authenticate as "a browser" and do all the manipulations with cookies and tickets manually in PHP. I was wondering if there is a better way how to work with CAS clients? I would really like to just provide my credentials in request header and not try to handle all the cookies and tickets.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for the proxy feature: web application A is protected by a CAS client and accesses a web service protected by a CAS client as well. So the CAS identity needs to be proxyfied from the web app to the web service.

Here are some links that can help:

- http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html
- https://www.casinthecloud.com/service.html?proxy#doc